# macOS installer cross compatibility between M1 and Intel

Tags: software-update, apple-silicon

Is a macOS installer I've made with `createinstallmedia` on an Intel-based Mac bootable on an M1-based Mac?

Comment: Have a look at: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). My read on it is as long as the hardware supports the version of **macOS** on the **USB Installer** it should work.

Comment: right, thank you, I'm just unsure as to whether or not apple transparently downloads you an apple silicon exclusive variant when downloading from an apple silicon mac, and vice versa on an intel mac. will test my installer soon and post back here

Comment: Eric Reed, The reason I posted what I did, as a comment, is I'm not 100% sure. My guess it that's what the whole _universal binaries_ are supposed to be about. In any case, after you've tried and definitively know, you can self-answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macOS installers are compatible with both Intel and Apple Silicon (M1, M2, etc.)

### How to Verify

Here’s how I verified it:

**On an M1 machine** (running macOS Ventura):

- Went to [How to download macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) and srolled down to “Or use the App Store or your browser”
- Clicked Monterey 12 to download it via the App Store
- Created USB disk using `/Applications/Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/$VOLUME_NAME`

**On an Intel machine:**

- Booted from the USB disk
- Installed Monterey